# Nginx Http Upload Progress Module: Hide X-Progress-ID in URL

Tags: php, upload, module, nginx, progress

I'm using Nginx Http Upload Progress Module(http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule) for my video upload page(upload.php). Everything works fine, but after the video uploaded successfully, the URL display:

```
upload-success.php?X-Progress-ID=9040ccc12eb610ecb0362d5312e1b2fa
```

For some reason, i want to hide:

```
?X-Progress-ID=9040ccc12eb610ecb0362d5312e1b2fa
```

I've tried passing "X-Progress-ID" via hidden input in the form but it still display in the URL:

```
<input type="hidden" id="X-Progress-ID" name="X-Progress-ID" />
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])) {
    header("Location: /index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! you gave me an idea.

Comment: Btw. a bit out off topic, does your progress bar work? I can not figure it out. Here is my topic, maybe u could help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624731/javascript-issue-nginx-upload-progress-code-works-and-not